# External Storage Differences

Tags: android, pdf, memory, external, sd-card

This is potentially a stupid question, and i'm not sure if it goes here, but i'm confused.

Currently i have an LG Nexus 5 phone. An app i have made uses this filepath:

```
file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + filename;
```

This works great on my phone. It saves a PDF file so that i can access it.

I then go to plug in my tablet (Samsung) and try to use the app, only to find that it breaks due to saving the PDF in the file name above, producing this in the error log:

```
08-31 14:38:57.918  W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/31/08/2015 2:38:57 PM.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

After doing a bit of googling i can see that it's because i don't have an SD card in my tablet. This makes sense. But then i look at my phone and can't find an SD card slot anywhere? So why does it work and save on my phone, but not on my tablet.

Will i have to buy an SD card to make it work? The file i'm trying to save is a PDF file generated by iText. I've read that i apparently can't/shouldn't save this to internal storage either.

Any explinations/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + filename;'. What is the type of 'file' ? What is the value of 'filename'? This code can never work. It should at least be 'file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + filename;' Please tell also the value of '.getPath()'. '/storage/emulated/0/31/08/2015 2:38:57 PM.pdf' ??? Is that the full path? Never saw such a path. If that is the path you used then remove the : characters. They are forbidden in paths. Otherwise show more code. Code should work without a removable micro SD card too.

Comment: I figured this out by pure coincidence this morning. Changed the file name to a simple "Hello.pdf" and it worked like a charm. Found out (as you say) the "/" characters through the path are throwing it off so it's unable to find the file. All solved now. Thank you though! 

Just for the record, my file name was the following:
filename = "/" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ".pdf";

Comment: 'I figured this out by pure coincidence this morning'. By pure coincidence? Hmmm..

Comment: Yeah. I decided to go back to basics and just change my filename to "Hello.pdf" as i thought the slashes might be throwing the filepath off in the Samsung. Turns out it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()`, traditionally is part of an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like i'll have to buy a cheap SD Card.

Comment: @greenapps what is wrong with this ans? can you elaborate?

Comment: Read my comment below the question.